# Maps to the group completion

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, loop-spaces

Let $M$ be an <strike>H-space</strike>, **topological monoid** (homotopy-commutative if necessary):

What does the group comletion $\Omega BM$ represent in homotopy category? Is $[X,\Omega B M]$ always equal to the universal group associated to $[X,M]$?

Thanks!

Comment: See references to [group completion](http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/group+completion) in nLab

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I didn't find a relevant result in the reference by May in nLab, and also in "infinite loop spaces" by Adams. Do you know a reference discussing this question?

Comment: The most relevant one is I think Quillen's paper also referenced there. It is in the simplicial context though.

Comment: Surely being an H-space isn't a sufficient condition to admit a delooping?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan it must be group-like

Comment: @Mostafa: The classifying space doesn't exist for general $H$-spaces $M$. The usual condition is that you need a full blown monoid structure.

Comment: Qiaochu & @Fernando: No on both counts. There are grouplike (in fact connected) $H$-spaces which *do not* deloop. $S^7$ is such an example. You appear to be ignoring higher associativity.

Comment: @JohnKlein I meant it's necessary, of course the H-structure should be extendable to an A-infinity structure

Answer (score 4):

Section 1 of ``James maps, Segal maps, and the Kahn-Priddy theorem, by J. Caruso, F.R. Cohen, L.R. Taylor, and myself (http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/PAPERS/48.pdf) is entitled 
"Universal properties of group completions".  With an appropriate and standard definition of a group completion $g\colon X\to Y$ of $H$-spaces, Lemma 1.1 there observes that if $Y$ is grouplike, then the functor $[-,Y]$ takes homology isomorphisms to isomorphisms.  At least if $\pi_0(X)$ contains a countable cofinal sequence, Proposition 1.2 then gives a universal property of a group completion $g$ in terms of weak homotopy classes of maps: for a weak $H$-map $f\colon X \to Z$, where $Z$ is grouplike, there is a weak $H$-map $\tilde{f}\colon Y \to Z$ such that $\tilde f\circ g \simeq f$, and $\tilde{f}$ is unique up to weak homotopy. Corollary 1.3 then interprets this to say that on finite CW-complexes $A$, 
$g_{*}\colon [A,X]\to [A,Y]$ is universal in a reasonable sense of abelian monoid valued  represented functors.  The section was meant to clarify observations of Segal in "Operations in stable homotopy theory". I was never satisfied with this, but it was the best I could do.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your second question is usually no.  For example, take $M = \coprod_P BAut(P)$, where $P$ runs over a set of representatives for the isomorphism classes of finitely generated projective modules over a (discrete) ring $R$.  Then $\pi_m BAut(P) = 0$ for $m\neq 1$ (this is just the classifying space of a discrete group), so every map $S^m \to BAut(P)$ ($m>1$) is nullhomotopic and we find that the monoid of (unbased) homotopy classes of (unbased) maps $[S^m, M]$ is just the monoid of isomorphism classes of finitely generated projective $R$-modules.  So the universal group associated to this is just $K_0 (R)$.  On the other hand, $\pi_m \Omega BM = K_{m} (R)$, Quillen's higher K-theory groups of $R$, which are much more complicated.  As Neil points out in the comments, this implies that $[S^m, \Omega BM] = \pi_0 \Omega BM \times \pi_m \Omega BM = K_0 (R) \times K_m (R)$.

(One can use the McDuff-Segal version of the group completion theorem here, which identifies $\Omega BM$ up to homotopy as the plus construction applied to $K_0 (R) \times BGL(\infty, R)$. This is discussed in McDuff-Segal; see Example 2 on p. 283 and Remark 2 on p. 280.)

Comment: You probably want to be working in the based category, so $[S^m,M]$ should be $\pi_m(BAut(0))=0$ rather than $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning that in the positive direction, Proposition 4.6 of arxiv.org/abs/1206.3341v3 gives conditions under which $\pi_k \Omega BM$ is isomorphic to $Gr[S^k, M]/Gr(pi_0 M)$, where Gr means the universal group and [,] means the set of unbased homotopy classes of unbased maps.  But I don't know any situations where the hypotheses of this result are satisfied, apart from the examples studied in that paper.

Comment: @NeilStrickland I wanted to use unbased maps.  Certainly $\Omega BM$ sees more information about $M$ than just the identity component, so it seems to make more sense to think about unbased maps into $M$ when asking about the relationship with maps into $\Omega BM$.  (And I guess I've gotten used to Hatcher's notation, where $[,]$ is unbased maps and $\langle, \rangle$ is based maps.)

Comment: @DanRamras What is $pi_0 M$ in your comment?

Comment: @Mostafa Should have been $\pi_0 M$, i.e. the monoid of path components.

Comment: By the result in your paper, it seems that the second question has affirmative answer when the connected components of $M$ are simply-connected and $\pi_0 M$ is stably group-like  (like the situation in topological K-theories). Is this correct?

Comment: @DanRamras: if you want to use unbased maps, then you should compare with $[S^m,\Omega BM]=K_0(R)\times K_m(R)$, rather than $K_m(R)$.

Comment: @NeilStrickland Agreed.  I added that to the answer.

Comment: @Mostafa, I agree that the result in my paper applies to topological K-theory (this is pretty close to the examples in the paper).  I don't immediately see why simple connectivity is sufficient, but I haven't really thought about it.  Maybe we should discuss by email?  You can find my address easily.

Comment: @Mostafa I checked that simple connectivity is indeed sufficient.  In fact, if $M$ is stably group-like with respect to $m_0$, it's enough to have a homotopy $H: M \times M\times I \to M$ (exhibiting the homotopy commutativity of $M$) such that the loop $H(m_0^n, m_0^n, t)$ is nullhomotopic for each $n$.  In my papers, I assume the existence of a homotopy $H$ where this loop is constant at $m_0^{2n}$ for each $n$.  But the only place where this is used is in Lemma 3.13 of my article Algebr. Geom. Topol. 7 (2007) 2239-2270 (http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0703463) and that proof is easily extended.